# How to generate a C# class file from C# code behind?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a C# class (`classname.cs`) file at runtime and then use the class at runtime.

If it is, then how can I implement this?

Comment: Do you just want to create a file with some C# code or do you want it to becompiled and run at runtime?

Comment: Be careful! Most of the time when people do this, it is totally unnecessary and can cause major major headaches! Make sure you need to do this first.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class. There's a complete example on the MSDN page

Answer (score 0):

Check out the classes in the namespace `Microsoft.CSharp`. The `CSharpCodeProvider` has a method `CompileAssemblyFromSource` which can generate an in-memory assembly from your source.

Answer (score 0):

Please look [Generate C# Class Library project programatically with given fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254471/generate-c-sharp-class-library-project-programatically-with-given-fields/29254798#29254798). Not sure what means by runtime. But you can create many classes just clicking save (run t4 template).