# Generate C# Class Library project programatically with given fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a module that will generate class library project from given database columns that will include info class,dataprovider class and contorller class each having their own .cs file. What i have done now is that create info,provider and controller class.

I have researched to create class library project programatically but still not much success..**What i want to do is create a class library project programatically and move those files to the project folder.After that compile the library project and generate dll file and move that to bin folder of website.**

Can anyone please point me to the right direction or give some useful resources so that i can use that to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a T4 template and then you can programatically emit a C# class based on your database structure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have used the T4 template and it is very useful for same type of code generation. We can have XML for configuration (class and properties) and then automatically we can create classes for them. They are useful since the same configuration can be used for database layer, mapping properties to database fields etc. so your back-end layers can be automated.

Note: All classes should have common design. Also make class as `partial` so that you can always add more functionality to it.